# For small values of $x$, how good is the approximation $cos(x)\approx 1$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> For small values of $x$, how good is the approximation $cos(x)\approx 1$

How would one tackle this problem? I've found the Taylor expansion to be $cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - ...$, but how would one proceed?

Comment: How are you measuring how "good" it is? Do you want an error bound?

Comment: Do you know Taylor's Remainder Theorem?

Comment: I guess you are interested in either an absolute error bound $|x-\cos(x)|$ or a relative one $\frac{|x-\cos(x)|}{x}$

Comment: I guess I from the remainder would get $|R_n(x)|=|\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \cdot f^{(n+1)}(x)\cdot (x-0)^{n+1}|\leq|\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot x^{n+1}|$?